# There are two tables having 7 columns with 6 of char type and one of num type. Is there a way to find the added deleted and modifed rows?

Tags: sql, sas

The 7 columns are as follows. These columns are common for both table A and table B:

`Schema, tablename, columnname, type, length, label, notnull`

Table A has values:

| Schema | tablename | columnname | type | length | label | notnull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sch1 | instance | cntrycd | num | 124 | code | no' |
| sch1 | validate | validation | char | 123 | rules | Yes' |

Table B has values

| Schema | tablename | columnname | type | length | label | notnull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sch2 | procedure | steps | num | 123 | Rules | Yes |
| sch2 | validate | validation | char | 124 | rules | No |

The output that is expected is (in a tabular format)

| Schema | tablename | columnname | type | length | label | notnull | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sch1 | instance | cntrycd | num | 124 | code | no | --> Deleted |
| sch2 | procedure | steps | num | 123 | Rules | Yes | --> Added |
| sch2 | validate | validation | char | 124 | rules | No | --> Modified* |

* As there were few of the columns that got modified example: Length and notnull columns for this record is modified)

In case of modified even if in one of the columns is changed and rest all the records remain the same then it should flag it as modified.

Unable to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi - you haven't really explained anything regarding the logic being employed. What's the relationship (if any) between the 2 tables? How are you determining whether a record has been added, modified, deleted (or not changed)? Please also update your question with the SQL you've managed to write so far and what the issue is with it

Comment: The comparison requires a key.  The example *modified* is only true if the key is tablename & columnname. So, it appears you want to compare columns of schema **sch1** with schema **sch2**.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the records are uniquely keyed by `tablename, columnname`

Proc COMPARE is an effective too for discovering and evaluating the differences between two keyed data sets.  There are numerous other techniques as well:

- DATA; MODIFY
- DATA; MERGE
- DATA; hash()
- SQL; FULL JOIN

Example:

```
proc sql;
  create table one (
    Schema char(10)
  , tablename char(32)
  , columnname char(32)
  , type char(4)
  , length num
  , label char(200)
  , notnull char(3)
  );

  create table two like one;

insert into one
values ('sch1','instance','cntrycd','num',124,'code','no')
values ('sch1','validate','validation','char',123,'rules','Yes')
;

insert into two 
values ('sch2','procedure','steps','num',123,'Rules','Yes')
values ('sch2','validate','validation','char',124,'rulez','No')
;

proc compare noprint base=one compare=two outall
  out=comparison 
;
  id tablename columnname;
  var type length label notnull;
run;
```